# For a 2 variable function, prove that the linear approximation is less than the real value for all x and y

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider $f : \Bbb R^{2} → \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x,y) = x^{2} + 3y^{4}$. Prove that $f(x,y) ≥ L(x,y)$ for all $(x, y)$ in $\Bbb R^{2}.$

I found the linear approximation:
$$L = f(x,y) + f'x(a,b)(x-a) + f'y(a,b)(y-b)$$
$$L = -x^{2} - 9y^{4} - 2a + 12y^{3}b$$

Not sure how to prove that that is less than $f(x,y)$

Do I use Taylor's theorem?

Comment: Your linear approximation is not linear. At least it's not clear: are $x,y$ varying or is it $a,b$?

Comment: @Bob: Sorry I did not answer your question; would you like me to delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You know that the best local linear approximation to $f(x,y)$  at $(x_0,y_0)$is given by the tangent plane $f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$. If the statement is true for all linear approximations, then it would be true for the tangent plane, i.e., it should be the case that $$f(x_0,y_0)-[f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)]>0 $$, for all $(x_0,y_0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, which in this case is: $$x_0^2+3y_0^4-[2x_0(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+12y_0^3(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)]>0 $$.

I think this is an issue of convexity; the 3D equivalent of having $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ differentiable, with $f'(x)$ always below the graph. Notice the plot of this function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E2%2B3y%5E4

Comment: So how do I apply that to 2 variables?

Comment: You can try to prove the above inequality; let me think of a clearer answer.

Comment: I think we can use Gaussian curvature, which should be larger than 0.

Comment: Still don't understand how I would answer the question. I have not learned Gaussian curvature yet.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had a better answer; let me think for a bit, aI may just delete the answer.